# Why Tomcat systematically reloads my webapp after startup?

Tags: tomcat

I deploy a webapp on tomcat 9. My webapp is deployed on tomcat startup.
I would like to know why about 10 seconds after my webapp startup ends, it reloads systematically.
The log between startup and reload are the following (at root level TRACE) :

```
2021-11-05 10:24:47.966  INFO M044-1867436 --- [              main] o.a.c.s.Catalina                         : Le démarrage du serveur a pris [12 672] millisecondes
2021-11-05 10:24:57.979  INFO M044-1867436 --- [Catalina-utility-1] o.a.c.c.StandardContext                  : Le rechargement du contexte [/exemple] a démarré
```

It appears on a tomcat on eclipse, docker or on a tomcat standalone. It doesn't appear with a tomcat embedded with Spring Boot.
I don't know if it matters, I see that the thread which reload is named *Catalina-utility* and not *main* like at startup.

I lookup tomcat output, but I don't see any additionnal log information.
I lookup classes folder for changes with *inotifywait*, but I didn't see any changes between the end of the startup and the reload.

Do you have any idea of what could cause the reload of my webapp ?

Comment: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-reload

Comment: That isn't a default Tomcat installation. The log messages are in the wrong format.